# Given a prime number $p$ sastify $p^2\mid 2^{p-1}-1$. Prove that for all natural numbers $n$, $(p-1)(p!+2^n)$ has at least $3$ prime divisors

Tags: number-theory

After developing some of my ideas, I ends up at the situation where the exact power of $p!$ is equal to $n$, since in the other situations, it immediately show that $(p-1)(p!+2^n)$ has at least 3 prime divisors without the need of the input. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Those prime numbers are very rare: https://oeis.org/A001220

Comment: @StinkingBishop True, they are called Wieferich primes. Only two are known, but infinite many should exist. What I wonder is how the OP arrived at this particular expression.

Comment: anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Let $r=order(2\bmod p)$ which divides $p-1$. We have $2^r = 1+ap\bmod p^2$.
Your assumption $2^{p-1}=1\bmod p^2$  gives that $p$ is odd so $p-1=2^k(2l+1)$ and
$$2^{p-1} = (1+ap)^{(p-1)/r}=1+a\frac{p-1}rp\bmod p^2$$
Which implies that $a=0\bmod p$ ie. $2^r=1\bmod p^2$.

It can't be that $l=0$ as otherwise $r=2k$ and $ 2^r=(p-1)^2\ne 1\bmod p^2$.

The only prime dividing both $p-1$ and $p!+2^n$ is $2$ so we know that $2l+1$ and $p!+2^n$ are coprime.

> It remains to show that some odd prime divides $p!+2^n$ ie. that $p!+2^n$ is not a power of $2$.

Note that $p!\ne 0\bmod p^2$.

> If $p!+2^n=2^m$ then it must be that $2^n=2^m \bmod p$ which gives $n=m\bmod r$ so that $2^n=2^m \bmod p^2$ and hence $p!+2^n\ne 2^m \bmod p^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not able to follow your last paragraph, i.e., to see why $p!+2^n$ cannot be a power of $2$. What if $n$ and $m$ are congruent mod $r$?

Comment: If $n\equiv m\bmod r$ then $p!+2^n\equiv cp+2^n \equiv  cp+2^m\not\equiv 2^m \bmod p^2$ @Mike

Comment: I should rephrase what I wrote. If $p!+2^n=2^m$ for some integer $m$, then $p!+2^n$ and $2^m$ are [clearly] congruent mod $p$ and mod $p^2$. As $p|p!$ this gives $2^n$ and $2^m$ must be congruent mod $p$, and thus, as per the top paragraph, $2^m$  must be congruent mod $p^2$ with not only $2^n+p!$ but also $2^n$. But as $p^2$ does not divide $p!$, this is impossible.

Comment: I do see it now though, thank you @reuns